# Are questions about obtaining a degree on-topic?

Tags: support, scope

I have a question about obtaining a grad degree in the sciences and I was wondering if it fits on the site.  It's not a physics questions *per se*, but I would consider it a question best asked of a physics community.

Answer (score 3):

It will be on topic on yet-to-come [Academia proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/16617/academia).

For now, I agree that chat is a proper place.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure other people will disagree, so don't consider this the official word just yet, but I would probably consider questions like that off topic. We've had a few in the past, but that was before the site really got into a groove. It might depend on exactly what your question is, though, so if you edit that into your post here, that would help.

Either way, you're certainly welcome to bring it up in the chat room.

*EDIT*: I'll throw this out here for people who may be reading it in the future: when deciding if a question is on topic, the criterion we look at is "Is this question about physics?", **not** "Are physicists the best people to answer this question?"